# Teradata NORMALIZE options

Tags: teradata, normalize

I've been using td_normalize_overlap_meet to collape periods. I've seen some examples on forums that used CNT to identify the # of periods that were collapsed, and I've been searching for documentation to see if other similar functions exist but haven't found anything. I'm specifically looking for one that would keep the last collapsed period's start date. For example, say I have these periods:

```
+-----------+------------+
|Start Date | End Date   |
+-----------+------------+
|2018-01-02 | 2018-01-04 |
|2018-01-05 | 2018-01-07 |
|2018-01-08 | 2018-01-10 |
+-----------+------------+
```

And I collapse them into this:

```
+-----------+------------+-----+
|Start Date | End Date   | CNT |
+-----------+------------+-----+
|2018-01-02 | 2018-01-10 | 3   |
+-----------+------------+-----+
```

Is there a function similar to CNT that would give me this?

```
+-----------+------------+-----+------------------------------------+
|Start Date | End Date   | CNT | Last Collapsed Period's Start Date |
+-----------+------------+-----+------------------------------------+
|2018-01-02 | 2018-01-10 | 3   | 2018-01-08                         |
+-----------+------------+-----+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: There's no fubntion for it, but `td_normalize_overlap_meet` can be rewritten in several ways (in fact you don't need it at all when using `SELECT NORMALZE`. What's your Teradata release, does it support `nPath`?

Comment: I saw the `SELECT NORMALIZE` clause for the first time the other day I need to start using it. I'm on release 16.20.48.01. I spent a couple days playing w/ `nPath` a while ago and gave up when I came across `td_normalize_overlap_meet` in a post response from you. I can get what I need by joining back to the pre-collapsed periods after normalizing; I was just curious if there was a way to do it inside normalize to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT NORMALIZE` is really easy syntax (especially compared to those `td_normalize...`functions), but can't be used for getting the *count of rows* or the *last row's start date*.

The easiest way to get the desired result applies the `nPath` table operator. Assuming there's more than a single group of rows to be normalized:

```
WITH cte AS 
 ( -- the base Select creating the not yet normalized rows
   SELECT *
   FROM mytab
 )
SELECT * 
FROM 
   NPath(ON cte
         PARTITION BY col -- grouping column(s)
         ORDER BY Start_date
         USING
           MODE (NonOverlapping)
           Symbols (start_date-1 > lag(end_date, 1, date '0001-01-01') AS newgrp, -- starting row of a group of overlapping rows
                    start_date-1 <= lag(end_date, 1, ) as x)                      -- overlapping row
           Pattern ('newgrp.x*')                                                  -- start plus overlapping rows
           RESULT(First (col OF newgrp) AS col,                                   -- grouping column(s)
                  first (start_date OF ANY(newgrp, x)) AS start_date,             -- start date of group 
                  last  (end_date   OF ANY(newgrp, x)) AS end_date,               -- end date of group
                  Count (*          OF ANY(newgrp, x)) AS Cnt,                    -- number of rows in group
                  last  (start_date OF ANY(newgrp, x)) AS last_start              -- start date of last row in group
                 )
        );
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like an elegant way of doing it, I'll be sure to play around w/ nPath again to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: `nPath` is great, it's intended for pattern matching (similar to Oracle's MATCH_RECOGNIZE), but can be used for other tasks, too, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685218/2527905 to replace LIST_AGG

Comment: Yea the symbols clause reminded me of MATCH_RECOGNIZE which I use but don't fully understand either. I've been using XMLAGG to replace LISTAGG, is nPath more efficient? Oops, just looked at the post you linked and saw your last sentence!

Comment: @dnoeth- Npath isn't just a Vantage thing?

Comment: @Andrew: The full stack of (Aster) functions is only in the Machine Learing/Graph Engine, but since 15.10 some of those Aster functions have been ported to the SQL-engine, see https://docs.teradata.com/reader/CWVY0AJy8wyyf7Sm0EsK~w/stx2kTy1WcWu1rh1N7_uKg