# How to merge integers from multiple cells to one in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I am giving up the SQL solution, and now switching to Pandas.
My goal is to merge the integer data as below:

Data input:

| ACCT | SOURCES |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 4 |

expected output:

| ACCT | SOURCES |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 4 |

Comment: have you tried https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/4xbLyOA_385QLYctkj~hjw ?

Comment: Hi Bursov, yes your solution can successfully change the data type from integer to varchar. But I still couldn't apply existing solutions to get the result I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
  ACCT  SOURCES
0    A        1
1    A        2
2    B        1
3    C        4
```

Doing:

```
df.SOURCES = df.SOURCES.astype(str)
df = df.groupby('ACCT', as_index=False)['SOURCES'].agg(','.join)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  ACCT SOURCES
0    A     1,2
1    B       1
2    C       4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XMLAGG to concatenate them together. It puts spaces between the values, you can replace those with a comma.
The innermost cast is if sources is actually defined as integer, not char/varchar.

```
select
acct,
oreplace(cast(xmlagg(cast(sources as varchar(5))) as varchar(10000)),' ',',')
from
<your table>
group by
acct
```

Comment: Hi Andrew,  it shows failed as the arguments of the cast function must be of the same character data type.

Comment: That exact query works for me.

Comment: For the CAST from XML type (returned by XMLAGG) to VARCHAR, explicitly specify the result to be UNICODE, i.e. `as VARCHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE`. BTW - nPath is more efficient than XMLAGG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63683088/teradata-results-with-duplicate-values-converted-into-comma-delimited-strings/63685218#63685218